# Validation Form with Jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want besides the numbers to put a letter "p"    which is supported by validator. But I do not understand why the end is  placed the "Letters only please");... 
This is a validator for a price field and lets only numbers to input and I want to put the letter "p" to be accepted.
Here is my Jquery code, maybe this can help:

```
 jQuery('#dtf-form-backend').validate({
  rules: {
    contactName: {
      required: true,
      lettersonly: true
    },
    contactEmail: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    catId: {
      required: true
    },
    price: {
      required: false,
      priceonly: false
    }
  },
  messages: {
    contactName: {
      required: "Please enter your name",
      lettersonly: "No numbers or special symbols"
    },
    contactEmail: {
      required: "Email is required",
      email: "Please enter a valid email"
    },
    catId: {
      required: "Please choose category"
    },
    price: {
      required: "Please specify item price",
      priceonly: "Only number is accepted"
    }
  }
});


 jQuery.validator.addMethod("priceonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\,]+$/i.test(value);
}, "Letters only please");
```

Thx Elod !

Answer (score 0):

what you want? put a example a match. you want a match like this? 895p

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("priceonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9\,]+p$/i.test(value);
  }, "Letters only please");
```

Comment: This is a validator for a price field and lets only numbers to input and i want to put the letter "p" to be accepted.